# How to make the error messages not appear below the fields, but on top of the table Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing a Django site, I made a registration form, but I don't like the fact that error messages appear under the corresponding fields, thereby stretching the table
[image]

I want these messages to be displayed somewhere above the form, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

In your Html code, you are going to add this block of code to wherever you want the error message to appear which in this would be at the top of the table tag in your html code.